# Why isn't a part of the code displayed?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

There are two parts in the code below. The first part is displaying the image:

[image: First Part]

and the second one is for displaying the Entry details:

[image: Second Part output]

When I run either parts separately(as separate py scripts) I get the output like above clearly. I wanted to have both in a single window. So, I combined both into a single script, but I don't get the output for the first part.

But I get CLI output like below.

> First part
>
> Second part

From the above First part of widget not showing, but the second part is fine. I'm kindly asking for someone to clarify it.

```
from Tkinter import *

Row = ['Enter the platform :', ' Device IP :', 'Username :', 'Password :', 'GICCI IP :', 'Craft IP :', 'STC IP :', 'STC Port to reserve :']
root = Tk()
window1=Frame(root)
r = 0
# First Part
Nokia_image = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\vkandhav\\Desktop\\PY_IMAGE\\NOKIA.gif")
print "First part"
Label(window1, image=Nokia_image, width="300", height="70").pack()
Button(window1, text="Nokia Performance Automate Tool").pack()
# Second Part
for c in Row:
    if c == "Enter the platform :":
        print "Second part"
    Label(root, text=c, relief=RIDGE, width=30).grid(row=r, column=0,)
    if c == "Password :":
        Entry(root, relief=SUNKEN, show="*", width=40).grid(row=r, column=1)
    else:
        Entry(root, relief=SUNKEN, width=40).grid(row=r, column=1)
    r = r + 1

mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there any error u getting?

Comment: mainloop()} ???

Comment: No, when i have any print message in the code which is getting executed correctly, But window  not opening.

Comment: Your indentation is off (at least here it is) and `mainloop()` shouldn't have a closing brace (`}`) after it.

Comment: removed  the } still i don't get o/p.

Comment: Fix your indentation please, it matters. Make sure the code you're providing is a [mcve] to the question you're asking.

Comment: _"When i run both the separately i get o/p"_ - What is "o/p"? Also, what have you done to debug this? Have you verified the code is running? Have you verified the widgets are being created? Have you verified the variables contain what you think they should contain?

Comment: Bryan i completely changed the content about my problem with output. I hope it clearly mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You're *never* calling to display the frame which the widgets are in. Add:

```
window1.grid()
```

Comment: Thank you Nae, it's worked. I am very new to python and tkinter. Just started learning one day ago. If you don't mine can you give me clarity how second part worked without calling   root.grid()

Comment: @velpandian Because by default both `Tk` (or `Toplevel`) instances are shown w/o explicitly calling a layout manager by default.

Comment: Thank you, understood :)